# How to extract frames from a video java?

Tags: java, ffmpeg, xuggle

I'm working on a project to do analysis on a video, and I want to split the video into frames to process individually. I took a look at several open source libraries, including Xuggler and FFMPEG, but they are both outdated and unavailable for use. Is there a simple way that I can extract the frames from the video and process them as a collection of `BufferedImage`?

Comment: FFMPEG is still actively maintained http://ffmpeg.org/ the last release was this month...

Comment: Can you share the code that worked for you? (i.e, using openCV or something else)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) Image and Video processing free open source framework. And also has a good Java wrapper.

Comment: Can you please share the code to do this using openCV + java. I tried to extract frames but it is not working. I don't want to extract all the frames but I want to extract a particular frame at a given time in milliseconds

Comment: There are a lot of online examples on the internet, you can also check OpenCV tutorials. Good Luck!!

Answer (score 3):

Follow this code

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.IplImage;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.FrameGrabber.Exception;

public class Read{
    public static void main(String []args) throws IOException, Exception
    {
        FFmpegFrameGrabber frameGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("D:/video.mp4");
        frameGrabber.start();
        IplImage i;
        try {

            i = frameGrabber.grab();
            BufferedImage  bi = i.getBufferedImage();
            ImageIO.write(bi,"png", new File("D:/Img.png"));
            frameGrabber.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Your code will generate the image for first frame (second 1)
how to generate the image for a particular frame?

Answer (score 2):

Next I leave the code that @Rohit proposed, but updated to 2021

```
package com.example;
 
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.Frame;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.Java2DFrameConverter; 
public class Main { 
    public static void main(String []args) throws IOException, Exception
    {
        File myObj = new File("D:\\x\\x\\x\\x\\video.mp4");
        FFmpegFrameGrabber frameGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(myObj.getAbsoluteFile());
        frameGrabber.start(); 
        Frame f; 
        try {
            Java2DFrameConverter c = new Java2DFrameConverter(); 
            f = frameGrabber.grab();  
            BufferedImage bi = c.convert(f);
            ImageIO.write(bi,"png", new File("D:\\x\\x\\x\\x\\img.png"));
            frameGrabber.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```