# How do I extract all the frames from a video in Java?

Tags: java, ffmpeg

I'm trying to grab the frames from a video and put them into a collection of BufferedImage so I can use the images later. I tried to use the code in the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67492899/11483947) for this question, but it wasn't really helpful because the code they provided only grabs the first frame. How would I extract all the frames and put them into a collection?

Comment: https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber/getLengthInFrames might be of some help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, a little bit of Googling (and reading the source code), I was able to hobble together this basic concept.

The "obvious" solution was to loop over the frames in the video and extract them, the "un-obvious" solution was "how"?!

The two methods you need are `FFmpegFrameGrabber#getLengthInFrames` and `FFmpegFrameGrabber#setFrameNumber`, from there it's just a simple method of converting the current frame and writing it to a file (which has already been demonstrated from the previous question)

```
File videoFile = new File("Storm - 106630.mp4");
FFmpegFrameGrabber frameGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(videoFile.getAbsoluteFile());
frameGrabber.start();
Java2DFrameConverter c = new Java2DFrameConverter();
int frameCount = frameGrabber.getLengthInFrames();
for (int frameNumber = 0; frameNumber < frameCount; frameNumber++) {
    System.out.println("Extracting " + String.format("%04d", frameNumber) + " of " + String.format("%04d", frameCount) + " frames");
    frameGrabber.setFrameNumber(frameNumber);
    Frame f = frameGrabber.grab();
    BufferedImage bi = c.convert(f);
    ImageIO.write(bi, "png", new File("Frame " + String.format("%04d", frameNumber) + "-" + String.format("%04d", frameCount) + ".png"));
}
frameGrabber.stop();
```

Now, obviously, you could store the images into some kind of `List` in memory, just beware, depending on the size and length of the original video, this might run you into memory issues.

Comment: I will definitely look further into source codes so I can try to figure it own on my from now on

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenCV to extract frames in a video, try the below code. input is the video file path of your computer

```
 VideoCapture cap = new VideoCapture();

    String output = "resources/output";

    cap.open(input);

    int video_length = (int) cap.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
    int frames_per_second = (int) cap.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FPS);

    Mat frame = new Mat();

    if (cap.isOpened()) {

        System.out.println("Video is opened");
        System.out.println("Number of Frames: " + video_length);
        System.out.println(frames_per_second + " Frames per Second");

        System.out.println("Converting Video to images...");

        cap.read(frame);

        int frame_number = 0;

        while (cap.read(frame)) {
            Imgcodecs.imwrite(output + "/" + frame_number + ".jpg", frame);
            frame_number++;
        }

        cap.release();

        processingStatus = video_length + " Frames extracted";
        System.out.println(processingStatus);

    } else {
        processingStatus = "Failed";
        System.out.println(processingStatus);
    }
```